# Does the mean value property hold for arbitrary surfaces?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

A [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ satisfies, for all $\mathbf p\in\mathbb R^3$ and $r>0$,
$$f(\mathbf p)=\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_{S(r)} d\sigma\, f,$$
where $S(r)$ is the sphere of radius $r$ with center $\mathbf p$.
This is shown for example [in these notes](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ecmart07/Harmonic%20functions.pdf) (pdf alert).

I suppose a similar result holds for surfaces other than spheres. If this is the case, how is this more general case proved? Both explicit proofs and references to relevant sources are welcome.

Comment: How would you like to define "center" for a surface that's not a sphere? In particular, what's the center of a nice, symmtrically-placed tube around a trefoil knot?

Comment: Maybe not a satisfying answer, but the mean value property is true for both spheres and balls, which can be seen by radially integrating the mean value property for spheres